# Unexpected "margin-top" result

Tags: css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
}

body > header > h1 {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      EXAMPLE
    </h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

In this code, when I gave margin-top to the h1 element, I thought that only the h1 element should be affected, but the margin affected not only the h1 but also the body element and shifted it down. What is the reason of this?

There is no problem when i use flex on body.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason the margin applied to the `h1` element affects the `body` element as well is due to the default collapsing margins behavior in CSS. When two vertical margins of adjacent elements collapse, the resulting margin is the maximum of the two margins.

In your case, when you apply a margin to the `h1` element, the margin collapses with the default margin of the `body` element, resulting in the larger margin being applied to the `body` element as well.

To prevent this collapsing margin behavior and ensure that the margin applied to the `h1` element only affects itself, you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Use `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element:

   ```css
   body {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```

   By applying `overflow: hidden`, you establish a new block formatting context for the `body` element, which prevents the collapsing margin from affecting the surrounding elements.
2. Use `padding` instead of `margin` on the `body` element:

   ```css
   body {
     padding-top: 20px; /* Or any desired value */
   }
   ```

   By using `padding` on the `body` element instead of `margin`, the spacing will be applied within the element itself, and there will be no collapsing margin issue.
3. Use a wrapper `div` around the content within the `body` element:

   ```html
   <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
       <!-- Content here -->
     </div>
   </body>
   ```

   ```css
   body {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
   }

   .wrapper {
     margin-top: 20px; /* Or any desired value */
   }
   ```

   By introducing a wrapper `div`, you contain the content within a separate element, preventing the margin collapse between the `h1` and `body` elements.